# Slice method in JavaScript is removing unwanted characters

Tags: javascript, html

I have two functions which are being used to achieve a rollover effect:

```
function rollOver(elem) {
  console.log(elem.slice(elem.length - 1))
  document.getElementById(`${elem}`).src = "images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_" + elem.slice(elem.length - 1) + ".jpg?$staticlink$";
}

function rollOut(elem) {
  console.log(elem.slice(elem.length - 1))
  document.getElementById(`${elem}`).src = "images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_" + elem.slice(elem.length - 1) + ".jpg?$staticlink$";
}
```

And are called...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var rollOverCollectionA = document
    .getElementById("roll-over-collection-a")
    .querySelectorAll("img");
    rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);
    var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        on("mouseover", `#${rollOverCollectionA[i].id}`, function() {
          rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id); // Here!
        });
        on("mouseout", `#${rollOverCollectionA[i].id}`, function() {
          rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id); // And here!
        });
      }

});
```

This is the associated markup:

```
 <div id="roll-over-collection-a">
    <div class="one-third column">
        <a href="#">
          <img id="hover-1" class="u-max-full-width make-up-img color-palette" alt="Eyes on you - Color Palette" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_1.jpg?$staticlink$" />
        </a>
        <div class="button">
          <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1503A0115000')$">SHOP NOW</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third column">
        <a href="#">
          <img id="hover-2" class="u-max-full-width make-up-img" alt="Eyes on you - Eye Topper" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_2.jpg?$staticlink$" />
        </a>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1503A0115000')$">SHOP NOW</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third column">
        <a href="#">
          <img id="hover-3" class="u-max-full-width make-up-img" alt="Eyes on you - Eyeliner" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_3.jpg?$staticlink$" />
        </a>
        <div class="button">
          <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1503A0115000')$">SHOP NOW</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However when the `rollOver/rollOut` gets `rollOverCollectionA[i].id` (and we are on the first element for example) it should yield `hover-1` as a string and `elem.slice(elem.length - 1)` should equal `1`, again as a string.

```
function rollOver(elem) { 
  document.getElementById(`${elem}`).src = "xx/xx/x/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_" + elem.slice(elem.length - 1) + ".jpg?$staticlink$";
}
```

But I get back:

`"https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/v1541390570323/.jpg";`

Which yields a `404`, naturally.

Actually looking via the console I see the functions in the script tag like this:

```
  function rollOver(elem) {
    console.log(elem.slice(elem.length - 1))
      document.getElementById(`${elem}`).src = "images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_" + elem.slice(elem.length - 1) + "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/v1541390570323/.jpg";
  }

  function rollOut(elem) {
    console.log(elem.slice(elem.length - 1))
      document.getElementById(`${elem}`).src = "images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_" + elem.slice(elem.length - 1) + "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/v1541390570323/.jpg";
  }
```

So can anyone tell me why the slice method is outputting

`https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/v1541390570323/.jpg`

instead of

`https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/v1541390570323/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_1.jpg`

**UPDATE**

Thought this was an interesting visual. Instead of the string `1` getting inserted its inserted `ihttps://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/v1541390570323/.jpg`

[image]

Live Example:

```js
function rollOver(elem) {
  console.log(elem.slice(elem.length - 1))
  document.getElementById(`${elem}`).src = "images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_" + elem.slice(elem.length - 1) + ".jpg?$staticlink$";
  console.log("src = " + document.getElementById(`${elem}`).src);
}

function rollOut(elem) {
  console.log(elem.slice(elem.length - 1))
  document.getElementById(`${elem}`).src = "images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_" + elem.slice(elem.length - 1) + ".jpg?$staticlink$";
  console.log("src = " + document.getElementById(`${elem}`).src);
}

function on(eventName, selector, callback) {
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(eventName, callback);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var rollOverCollectionA = document
    .getElementById("roll-over-collection-a")
    .querySelectorAll("img");
    rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);
    var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        on("mouseover", `#${rollOverCollectionA[i].id}`, function() {
          rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id); // Here!
        });
        on("mouseout", `#${rollOverCollectionA[i].id}`, function() {
          rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id); // And here!
        });
      }

});
```

```html
<div id="roll-over-collection-a">
    <div class="one-third column">
        <a href="#">
          <img id="hover-1" class="u-max-full-width make-up-img color-palette" alt="Eyes on you - Color Palette" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_1.jpg?$staticlink$" />
        </a>
        <div class="button">
          <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1503A0115000')$">SHOP NOW</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third column">
        <a href="#">
          <img id="hover-2" class="u-max-full-width make-up-img" alt="Eyes on you - Eye Topper" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_2.jpg?$staticlink$" />
        </a>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1503A0115000')$">SHOP NOW</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third column">
        <a href="#">
          <img id="hover-3" class="u-max-full-width make-up-img" alt="Eyes on you - Eyeliner" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_3.jpg?$staticlink$" />
        </a>
        <div class="button">
          <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1503A0115000')$">SHOP NOW</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `elem.slice(elem.length - 1)` to equal?  That simply returns the last character of `elem`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I've copied your code into a Stack Snippet at the end of the question, added the missing `on` function (it was fairly clear what it did), and the `console.log` lines show that `slice` is working correctly. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets as I have in my edit. ([Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).)

Comment: @ScottSauyet I expect the `slice()` method to return `1`.

Comment: Well T.J's snippet demonstrates that it is `1`.  You might improve this a bit by adding `console.clear()` to the beginning of `rollover`.  You could also log the value you're building for the `src`, and it looks to me to be correct when I try it.

Comment: I am using a `CMS` which explains the syntax after the the file extensions `?$staticlink$` and tags elsewhere. Maybe that's it?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz - I wouldn't have thought so. The substitutions by the CMS would already have occurred on the strings in the code before it ran, right? In any case, those substitutions aren't in the ID values...